# Why the results when python script run were different on each interpreter including classmethod / property?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8

The results were different.
Why?
Please, tell me the reason.

```py
class Test:

    @classmethod
    @property
    def test1(cls):
        return "test1_msg"

print(Test.test1)
```

■ Result1

1. The result on Python ~~3.8.2~~ **3.9.4** installed by homebrew on MacOS(v10.14.6).
2. The result: `test1_msg` was shown.
3. The above result was what I expected.

■ Result2

1. The result both belows.

   1. on **Python 3.8.5** installed by apt @ Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
   2. on **PyPy3.7 installed by homebrew of MacOS**(v10.14.6)
2. The result: `<bound method ? of <class '__main__.Test'>>`
3. The above result was what I did not expect.

Comment: The behavior you're expecting is Python 3.9 behavior. You were almost certainly not running Python 3.8.2 when you got the behavior you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will confirm the fact you told. Please wait.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code was run in I expected after installed py3.9.0 into Ubuntu server.